# Magento 2: Something went wrong while enabling the profiler

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento-framework

I have a problem with enabling html profiler in Magento 2 by command

> php bin/magento dev:profiler:enable html

It shows me this message: Something went wrong while enabling the profiler.
[image]

Comment: Have you check the Magento Log file? The Orignal error desription provided there.